# how to display images based on text box value from a gallery with minimum code jquery or javascript show below very helpful for me

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css">
  
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.0/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
let count,count1,count2,count3,count4,count5,count6,count7;

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
        $("[id^='no']").hide();
       
        $("#clsSub").click(function(){
          var imgval =  document.getElementById("divimages").value;
          var drpval =  document.getElementById("dropZone").value;
         if(imgval === '1'){
            $("#no1" ).show()
          }
          else if(imgval === '2' && drpval !== ''){
                  $("#no1, #no2" ).show()
          }
          else if(imgval === '3' && drpval !== ''){
            $("#no1, #no2, #no3" ).show()
          }
          else if(imgval === '4' && drpval !== ''){
            $("#no1, #no2, #no3, #no4" ).show()
          }
          else if(imgval === '5' && drpval !== ''){
            $("#no1, #no2, #no3, #no4, #no5" ).show()
          }
          else if(imgval === '6' && drpval !== ''){
            $("#no1, #no2, #no3, #no4, #no5, #no6" ).show()
          }
          else if(imgval === '7' && drpval !== ''){
            $("#no1, #no2, #no3, #no4, #no5, #no6, #no7" ).show()
          }
          else if(imgval === '8' && drpval !== ''){
            $("#no1, #no2, #no3, #no4, #no5, #no6, #no7, #no8" ).show()
          }
          else if(imgval === '9' && drpval !== ''){
            $("#no1, #no2, #no3, #no4, #no5, #no6, #no7, #no8, #no9" ).show()
          }
          else if(imgval === '10' && drpval !== ''){
            $("#no1, #no2, #no3, #no4, #no5, #no6, #no7, #no8, #no9, #no10" ).show()
          }
          else if(imgval === '11' && drpval !== ''){
            $("#no1, #no2, #no3, #no4, #no5, #no6, #no7, #no8, #no9, #no10, #no11" ).show()
          }
          else if(imgval === '12' && drpval !== ''){
            $("#no1, #no2, #no3, #no4, #no5, #no6, #no7, #no8, #no9, #no10, #no11, #no12" ).show()
          }
          else if(imgval === '13' && drpval !== ''){
            $("#no1, #no2, #no3, #no4, #no5, #no6, #no7, #no8, #no9, #no10, #no11, #no12, #no13" ).show()
          }
          else if(imgval === '14' && drpval !== ''){
            $("#no1, #no2, #no3, #no4, #no5, #no6, #no7, #no8, #no9, #no10, #no11, #no12, #no13, #no14" ).show()
          }
          else if(imgval === '15' && drpval !== ''){
            $("#no1, #no2, #no3, #no4, #no5, #no6, #no7, #no8, #no9, #no10, #no11, #no12, #no13, #no14, #no15" ).show()
          }
          else if(imgval === '16' && drpval !== ''){
            $("#no1, #no2, #no3, #no4, #no5, #no6, #no7, #no8, #no9, #no10, #no11, #no12, #no13, #no14, #no15, #no16" ).show()
          }
          else if(imgval === '17' && drpval !== ''){
            $("#no1, #no2, #no3, #no4, #no5, #no6, #no7, #no8, #no9, #no10, #no11, #no12, #no13, #no14, #no15, #no16, #no17" ).show()
          }
          else if(imgval === '18' && drpval !== ''){
            $("#no1, #no2, #no3, #no4, #no5, #no6, #no7, #no8, #no9, #no10, #no11, #no12, #no13, #no14, #no15, #no16, #no17, #no18" ).show()
          }
          else if(imgval === '19' && drpval !== ''){
            $("#no1, #no2, #no3, #no4, #no5, #no6, #no7, #no8, #no9, #no10, #no11, #no12, #no13, #no14, #no15, #no16, #no17, #no18, #no19" ).show()
          }
          else if(imgval === '20' && drpval !== ''){
            $("#no1, #no2, #no3, #no4, #no5, #no6, #no7, #no8, #no9, #no10, #no11, #no12, #no13, #no14, #no15, #no16, #no17, #no18, #no19, #no20" ).show()
          }
          else if(imgval === '21' && drpval !== ''){
            $("#no1, #no2, #no3, #no4, #no5, #no6, #no7, #no8, #no9, #no10, #no11, #no12, #no13, #no14, #no15, #no16, #no17, #no18, #no19, #no20, #no21").show()
          }
          else if(imgval === '22' && drpval !== ''){
            $("#no1, #no2, #no3, #no4, #no5, #no6, #no7, #no8, #no9, #no10, #no11, #no12, #no13, #no14, #no15, #no16, #no17, #no18, #no19, #no20, #no21, #no22" ).show()
          }
          else if(imgval === '23' && drpval !== ''){
            $("#no1, #no2, #no3, #no4, #no5, #no6, #no7, #no8, #no9, #no10, #no11, #no12, #no13, #no14, #no15, #no16, #no17, #no18, #no19, #no20, #no21, #no22, #no23").show()
          }
          else if(imgval === '24' && drpval !== ''){
            $("#no1, #no2, #no3, #no4, #no5, #no6, #no7, #no8, #no9, #no10, #no11, #no12, #no13, #no14, #no15, #no16, #no17, #no18, #no19, #no20, #no21, #no22, #no23, #no24" ).show()
          }
          else if(imgval === '25' && drpval !== ''){
            $("#no1, #no2, #no3, #no4, #no5, #no6, #no7, #no8, #no9, #no10, #no11, #no12, #no13, #no14, #no15, #no16, #no17, #no18, #no19, #no20, #no21, #no22, #no23, #no24, #no25" ).show()
          }
          else if(imgval === '26' && drpval !== ''){
            $("#no1, #no2, #no3, #no4, #no5, #no6, #no7, #no8, #no9, #no10, #no11, #no12, #no13, #no14, #no15, #no16, #no17, #no18, #no19, #no20, #no21, #no22, #no23, #no24, #no25, #no26" ).show()
          }
          else if(imgval === '27' && drpval !== ''){
            $("#no1, #no2, #no3, #no4, #no5, #no6, #no7, #no8, #no9, #no10, #no11, #no12, #no13, #no14, #no15, #no16, #no17, #no18, #no19, #no20, #no21, #no22, #no23, #no24, #no25, #no26, #no27" ).show()
          }
          else if(imgval === '28' && drpval !== ''){
            $("#no1, #no2, #no3, #no4, #no5, #no6, #no7, #no8, #no9, #no10, #no11, #no12, #no13, #no14, #no15, #no16, #no17, #no18, #no19, #no20, #no21, #no22, #no23, #no24, #no26, #no27, #no28").show()
          }
          else if(imgval === '29' && drpval !== ''){
            $("#no1, #no2, #no3, #no4, #no5, #no6, #no7, #no8, #no9, #no10, #no11, #no12, #no13, #no14, #no15, #no16, #no17, #no18, #no19, #no20, #no21, #no22, #no23, #no24, #no25, #no26, #no27, #no28, #no29" ).show()
          }
          else if(imgval === '30' && drpval !== ''){
            $("#no1, #no2, #no3, #no4, #no5, #no6, #no7, #no8, #no9, #no10, #no11, #no12, #no13, #no14, #no15, #no16, #no17, #no18, #no19, #no20, #no21, #no22, #no23, #no24, #no24, #no25, #no26, #no27, #no28, #no29, #no30" ).show()
          }
         
     })     

  });
         
  </script>
  <style type="text/css">
    .imgC{
      
      width: 60px;
      height: 60px;
      margin-top: 5px;
    }
    .wth {
  height: 70px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}

  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
<!-- The Modal -->
  <div class="modal" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
      
        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Please Update the values</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>
        
        <!-- Modal body -->
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="row" >
                <div class="col-sm-5">
                <label>Number of images</label>
            </div>
            <div>
              <label>number of drop Zones</label>              
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                  <input type="text" id='divimages' name="text" class="form-control input-sm numbers" />
                </div>
            <div class="col-sm-5">                  
                <input type="text" name="" id='dropZone' value="" class="form-control input-sm drpimg" />
            </div>
                
                <div class="col-sm-2 btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="clsSub" onclick="dosubmit()">Submit</div>
            
                
            </div>

        </div>
        
        <!-- Modal footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- modal close -->

    <!-- container end -->

  <div class="container" style="border: 1px solid red; height: 250px; display: inline-flex;">
  <div class="row" id="gallery" style="width: 100%">  
    <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"  id="no1" src="images\1.png" class="imgC ">
  <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no2" src="images\2.png" class="imgC ">
  <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no3"  src="images\3.png" class="imgC ">
  <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no4"  src="images\4.png" class="imgC ">
  <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no5"  src="images\5.png" class="imgC ">
  <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no6"  src="images\6.png" class="imgC ">
  <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no7"  src="images\7.png" class="imgC ">
  <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no8"  src="images\8.png" class="imgC ">
  <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no9"  src="images\9.png" class="imgC ">
  <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no10" src="images\10.png" class="imgC ">
  <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no11" src="images\11.png" class="imgC ">
  <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no12" src="images\12.png" class="imgC ">
  <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no13" src="images\13.png" class="imgC ">
  <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no14" src="images\14.png" class="imgC ">
  <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no15" src="images\15.png" class="imgC ">
  <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no16" src="images\16.png" class="imgC ">
  <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no17" src="images\17.png" class="imgC ">
  <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no18" src="images\18.png" class="imgC ">
  <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no19" src="images\19.png" class="imgC ">
  <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no20" src="images\20.png" class="imgC ">
  <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no21" src="images\21.png" class="imgC ">
  <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no22" src="images\22.png" class="imgC ">
  <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no23" src="images\23.png" class="imgC ">
  <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no24" src="images\24.png" class="imgC ">
  <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no25" src="images\25.png" class="imgC ">
  <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no26" src="images\26.png" class="imgC ">
  <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no27" src="images\27.png" class="imgC ">
  <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no28" src="images\28.png" class="imgC ">
  <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no29" src="images\29.png" class="imgC ">

  </div>
</div><div>    
</div>  
</div>
```

Summary :- I want to display images from container randomly based on value enter in textbox
Example : Default all images will be in hidden . if I enter any number in text box 6 or 7 or 8 i have to display six or seven or eight images in container
i had tried with jquery but lt is taking lots of lines for code i want to reduce the code in short cut

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the 'less than' selector. Here is an example.

```js
$(function() {
  function showImages(int) {
    $("img[id^='no']").hide();
    $("img[id^='no']:lt(" + int + ")").show();
  }

  $('#myModal').modal('show');

  $("#clsSub").click(function() {
    var imgVal = parseInt($("#divimages").val());
    var drpVal = $("#dropZone").val();
    if (drpVal !== "" && imgVal <= 30) {
      showImages(imgVal);
      $('#myModal').modal('hide');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.imgC {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.wth {
  height: 70px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.0/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div class="modal" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Please Update the values</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>
        <!-- Modal body -->
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-5">
              <label>Number of images</label>
            </div>
            <div>
              <label>number of drop Zones</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
              <input type="text" id='divimages' name="text" class="form-control input-sm numbers" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
              <input type="text" name="" id='dropZone' value="" class="form-control input-sm drpimg" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="clsSub">Submit</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Modal footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- modal close -->
  <!-- container end -->

  <div class="container" style="border: 1px solid red; height: 250px; display: inline-flex;">
    <div class="row" id="gallery" style="width: 100%">
      <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no1" src="images\1.png" class="imgC ">
      <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no2" src="images\2.png" class="imgC ">
      <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no3" src="images\3.png" class="imgC ">
      <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no4" src="images\4.png" class="imgC ">
      <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no5" src="images\5.png" class="imgC ">
      <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no6" src="images\6.png" class="imgC ">
      <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no7" src="images\7.png" class="imgC ">
      <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no8" src="images\8.png" class="imgC ">
      <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no9" src="images\9.png" class="imgC ">
      <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no10" src="images\10.png" class="imgC ">
      <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no11" src="images\11.png" class="imgC ">
      <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no12" src="images\12.png" class="imgC ">
      <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no13" src="images\13.png" class="imgC ">
      <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no14" src="images\14.png" class="imgC ">
      <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no15" src="images\15.png" class="imgC ">
      <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no16" src="images\16.png" class="imgC ">
      <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no17" src="images\17.png" class="imgC ">
      <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no18" src="images\18.png" class="imgC ">
      <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no19" src="images\19.png" class="imgC ">
      <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no20" src="images\20.png" class="imgC ">
      <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no21" src="images\21.png" class="imgC ">
      <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no22" src="images\22.png" class="imgC ">
      <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no23" src="images\23.png" class="imgC ">
      <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no24" src="images\24.png" class="imgC ">
      <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no25" src="images\25.png" class="imgC ">
      <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no26" src="images\26.png" class="imgC ">
      <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no27" src="images\27.png" class="imgC ">
      <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no28" src="images\28.png" class="imgC ">
      <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no29" src="images\29.png" class="imgC ">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want it to be random, you need to adjust this a good amount.

```js
$(function() {
  function showImages(int) {
    $("img[id^='no']").removeClass("show").addClass("hide");
    for (var i = 0; i < int; i++) {
      var n = Math.floor(Math.random() * $("img[id^='no']:not('.show')").length);
      console.log(i, n);
      $("img[id^='no']:not('.show')").eq(n).toggleClass("hide show");
    }
  }

  $('#myModal').modal('show');

  $("#clsSub").click(function() {
    var imgVal = parseInt($("#divimages").val());
    var drpVal = $("#dropZone").val();
    if (drpVal !== "" && imgVal <= 30) {
      showImages(imgVal);
      $('#myModal').modal('hide');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.imgC {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.wth {
  height: 70px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.0/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div class="modal" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Please Update the values</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>
        <!-- Modal body -->
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-5">
              <label>Number of images</label>
            </div>
            <div>
              <label>number of drop Zones</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
              <input type="text" id='divimages' name="text" class="form-control input-sm numbers" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
              <input type="text" name="" id='dropZone' value="" class="form-control input-sm drpimg" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="clsSub">Submit</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Modal footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- modal close -->
  <!-- container end -->

  <div class="container" style="border: 1px solid red; height: 250px; display: inline-flex;">
    <div class="row" id="gallery" style="width: 100%">
      <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no1" src="images\1.png" class="imgC ">
      <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no2" src="images\2.png" class="imgC ">
      <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no3" src="images\3.png" class="imgC ">
      <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no4" src="images\4.png" class="imgC ">
      <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no5" src="images\5.png" class="imgC ">
      <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no6" src="images\6.png" class="imgC ">
      <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no7" src="images\7.png" class="imgC ">
      <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no8" src="images\8.png" class="imgC ">
      <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no9" src="images\9.png" class="imgC ">
      <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no10" src="images\10.png" class="imgC ">
      <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no11" src="images\11.png" class="imgC ">
      <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no12" src="images\12.png" class="imgC ">
      <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no13" src="images\13.png" class="imgC ">
      <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no14" src="images\14.png" class="imgC ">
      <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no15" src="images\15.png" class="imgC ">
      <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no16" src="images\16.png" class="imgC ">
      <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no17" src="images\17.png" class="imgC ">
      <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no18" src="images\18.png" class="imgC ">
      <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no19" src="images\19.png" class="imgC ">
      <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no20" src="images\20.png" class="imgC ">
      <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no21" src="images\21.png" class="imgC ">
      <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no22" src="images\22.png" class="imgC ">
      <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no23" src="images\23.png" class="imgC ">
      <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no24" src="images\24.png" class="imgC ">
      <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no25" src="images\25.png" class="imgC ">
      <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no26" src="images\26.png" class="imgC ">
      <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no27" src="images\27.png" class="imgC ">
      <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no28" src="images\28.png" class="imgC ">
      <img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="no29" src="images\29.png" class="imgC ">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
  </div>
</div>
```